# How to get parameters from query in desired order?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute native query vie modifying SQL query after queryBuilder. So I got my query via

```
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL()
```

My query looks like this

```
SELECT p0_.id AS id_0 FROM ptable p0_ WHERE p0_.code = ? AND p0_.item_id IN (?)
```

But

```
$parameters = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getParameters()
```

returns parameters in order that they was added, but not how they are appears in sql query. Does it exists the way to get parameters in *right* order?

Parameters roughly looks like `['code', [1,2,3]]` or `[[1,2,3], 'code']` - order dependents on adding order.

*** Update. What I am trying to do

```
$newParameters = [];
foreach ($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getParameters() as $parameter) {
    $newParameters[count($newParameters) + 1] = $parameter->getValue();
}
$nativeQuery =
    $this->_em
        ->createNativeQuery('SELECT count(*) countItem FROM ('.$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL().') tmp', $rsm)
        ->setParameters($newParameters);// params order does matter
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon I saw your question I made a Test case and did what you trying to do number of times. But, I did not manage to get a random order as you are.

Are you using any framework or are you using Doctrine out of the box ? The below example is using Doctrine in Symfony 2.8.

**Using createQueryBuilder()**

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('p.id')
        ->from('ABCBundle:PTable', 'p')
        ->where('p.name = :p_name')
        ->setParameter('p_name', 'Test Data')
        ->andWhere('p.order IN (:p_order)')
        ->setParameter('p_order', array(4,5,6))
        ->getQuery();
```

This `print_r($qb->getSQL());` and `print_r($qb->getParameters());` give me following results and it has always been consistent,

```
SELECT f0_.id AS ID0 FROM p_table f0_ WHERE f0_.name = ? AND f0_.order IN (?)Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object
(
    [elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter Object
                (
                    [name:Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter:private] => name
                    [value:Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter:private] => Test Data
                    [type:Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter:private] => 2
                )

            [1] => Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter Object
                (
                    [name:Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter:private] => order
                    [value:Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4
                            [1] => 5
                            [2] => 6
                        )

                    [type:Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter:private] => 101
                )

        )

)
```

**Using createNativeQuery()**

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.id AS ID0 FROM p_table p WHERE p.name = :name AND p.order IN (:order)';
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter('name', 'Test Data');
$query->setParameter('corder', array(4,5,6));
print_r($query->getSQL());
print_r($query->getParameters());
```

The above order will always be the order of parameters that you set using `setParameter()`.

I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But try to rearrange setParameter like this $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p.id')
            ->from('ABCBundle:PTable', 'p')
            ->where('p.name = :p_name')
            ->setParameter('p_order', array(4,5,6))
            ->where('p.order IN (:p_order)')
            ->setParameter('p_name', 'HIS_DATA')
            ->getQuery();`

Comment: I have changed the order as you suggested. Then as expected the parameters array order changes. The new order is the `order array` sitting at the top and `name` sitting at the bottom. But, that is also consistent as I have tested number of times.

Comment: It woks when you works with query or queryBuilder. Order of params does not matter. But when you trying create new native via `createNativeQuery` params order does matter.

Comment: I have upadated my answer based on `createNativeQuery`. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: You have created query manually, then you have named placeholders. So order of params does not matter. But I am getting sql from Query class where placeholders are become unnamed (`?`), so order became important.

Comment: Yes I agree. If you are using question mark (`?`) instead of placeholders, the order is vital. If I find a way preserve the order when dealing with question marks, I will surely update my answer. Thank you.